# How to Consume java web-service (jetty) in C#

Tags: java, asp.net, web-services, jetty, web-reference

I am a newbie to C# development.

Scenario -

We have an application running on .NET 2.0 framework and IIS 6.5. Now, we have installed another application on a remote server which utilizes Jetty web server. For us to integrate both the applications we need to add a reference to a web service in jetty. I have found the web service  path on the server which is a .class file and I want to add a reference to my .NET application.

My problem is - how do I find the URL to add a web reference to the .NET application in Visual Studio ? or is there another way to integrate both the applications ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `.wsdl` of the .NET web service to generate a proxy class in the Jetty web server? I am assuming there is some type of discovery mechanism built into the Jetty web server for web service capabilities, right?

Comment: Agreed. If you get some sort of URL from Jetty, typically, you can add a web reference to that webservice in asp.net, by pointing to the "wsdl" path. This path is usually, "whatever the url is" + "?wsdl" tacked onto the end.